# Как реализовать плавное закрашивание SVG-элемента?

Tags: html, jquery, svg, svg-animation, tailwindcss

Мне нужно реализовать пошаговое закрашивание SVG картинки, при наведении на каждый блок определенного шага.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, при наведении на блок "Тех Диагностика" полоса должна закрашиваться вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код SVG.

```
      <div class="hidden lg:block xl:hidden absolute top-[195px] left-[90px]">
          <svg class="w-[750px] h-[333px]">
              <use xlink:href="#steps-line"/>
          </svg>
      </div>
```

А вот код одного из блоков

```
<div class="flex flex-row xl:ml-[100px] lg:mt-[215px] xl:mt-[120px]">
     <div class="transform translate-y-[-40px]">
          <img src="/static/images/redesign_redemption/step3.svg" alt="step3">
     </div>
     <div>
          <div class="text-xl font-medium mb-[6px]">Оформление документов</div>
          <div class="w-[70px] h-[25px] border-2 text-brand-gray font-bold border-brand-gray-light rounded-2xl text-center mb-[10px]">2 часа</div>
          <div class="text-[14px] mb-[10px]">
               Возьмем на себя оформление<br> полного пакета документов для<br> выкупа вашего авто.
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Как можно это реализовать? (желательно реализовать это с плавным закрашиванием)

Comment: Свойства `stroke-dashoffset` и `stroke-dasharray`. Через [dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) задаются размеры штрихов. А [dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) их сдвигает.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

как-то так

Кликайте по соответствующим пунктам.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg4" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGRBR.png" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  <path id="trace" stroke-dasharray="1651" stroke-dashoffset="1651" d="M321 190h369c50 0 53 90 0 90H163c-82 0-83 133-1 133h419"  fill="none" stroke="#2D4461" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" > 
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect1.click" dur="1.5s" values="1651;1450" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
      <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect2.click" dur="2s"    values="1450;1200"    fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
          <animate id="an3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect3.click" dur="3s" values="1200;350" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
              <animate id="an4" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect4.click" dur="2s" values="350;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" />
  </path>
 
  <g fill="transparent">
 <path id="rect1" d="M64 65h245l3 152-247-2z"  />
  <path id="rect2" d="m664 97 290 1v148l-290-1z"  />
  <path id="rect3" d="M140 289h252l1 116-252-2z" />
  <path id="rect4" d="M597 337h232l-1 125-231 3z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

*Вариант анимации заполнения трассы при наведении на пункт выполнения работы*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg4" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGRBR.png" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  <path id="trace" stroke-dasharray="1651" stroke-dashoffset="1651" d="M321 190h369c50 0 53 90 0 90H163c-82 0-83 133-1 133h419"  fill="none" stroke="#2D4461" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" > 
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect1.mouseover" dur="1.5s" values="1651;1450" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
      <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect2.mouseover" dur="2s"    values="1450;1200"    fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
          <animate id="an3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect3.mouseover" dur="3s" values="1200;350" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
              <animate id="an4" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect4.mouseover" dur="2s" values="350;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" />
  </path>
 
  <g fill="transparent">
 <path id="rect1" d="M64 65h245l3 152-247-2z"  />
  <path id="rect2" d="m664 97 290 1v148l-290-1z"  />
  <path id="rect3" d="M140 289h252l1 116-252-2z" />
  <path id="rect4" d="M597 337h232l-1 125-231 3z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

***Вариант с подсветкой выбора, добавлена адаптивность***

При наведении на любой пункт диаграммы, он подцвечивается и запускается анимация появления трассы до этого пункта

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.rect:hover {
fill:lime;
fill-opacity:0.3;
cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 8px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
        filter: drop-shadow(4px 8px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg4" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGRBR.png" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  <path id="trace" stroke-dasharray="1651" stroke-dashoffset="1651" d="M321 190h369c50 0 53 90 0 90H163c-82 0-83 133-1 133h419"  fill="none" stroke="#2D4461" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" > 
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect1.mouseover" dur="1.5s" values="1651;1450" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
      <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect2.mouseover" dur="2s"    values="1450;1200"    fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
          <animate id="an3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect3.mouseover" dur="3s" values="1200;350" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 
              <animate id="an4" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="rect4.mouseover" dur="2s" values="350;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" />
  </path>
 
  <g fill="transparent">
 <path class="rect" id="rect1" d="M64 65h245l3 152-247-2z"  />
  <path class="rect" id="rect2" d="m664 97 290 1v148l-290-1z"  />
  <path class="rect" id="rect3" d="M140 289h252l1 116-252-2z" />
  <path class="rect" id="rect4" d="M597 337h232l-1 125-231 3z" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы гуру SMIL! Не перестаю удивляться вашему таланту.

Comment: А реально ли реализовать такое при наведении?)

Comment: @IlyaZakharov добавил вариант с наведением

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Вы гений, сейчас попробую реализовать у себя на странице, заранее Спасибо!)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Да, принял, все супер) Сори, я тут новичок просто)

Answer (score 7):

Используются свойства [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) и [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray).

Через `stroke-dasharray` задаются размеры штрихов.

А `stroke-dashoffset` их сдвигает.

Анимацию можно делать через CSS `@keyframes`.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -5 100 30">
<defs>
<style>
#line{
  animation-name: lineanim;
  animation-duration: 5000ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes lineanim {
  0%   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 265px; }
}
</style>
</defs>
<path d="M90,20 L15,20 A5,5 0 1 1 15,10 L85,10 A5,5 0 1 0 85,0 L 10,0" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
<path id="line" d="M90,20 L15,20 A5,5 0 1 1 15,10 L85,10 A5,5 0 1 0 85,0 L 10,0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 260 0" />

</svg>
```

Второй пример без анимации `@keyframes`, но с анимацией перехода `transition`. Выбираете шаг - линия заполняется.

```css
#step1:checked ~ svg #line {stroke-dashoffset: 0px;}
#step2:checked ~ svg #line {stroke-dashoffset: 65px;}
#step3:checked ~ svg #line {stroke-dashoffset: 130px;}
#step4:checked ~ svg #line {stroke-dashoffset: 195px;}
#step5:checked ~ svg #line {stroke-dashoffset: 260px;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="step" value="1" id="step1"/><label for="step1">Step1</label>
<input type="radio" name="step" value="2" id="step2"/><label for="step2">Step2</label>
<input type="radio" name="step" value="3" id="step3"/><label for="step3">Step3</label>
<input type="radio" name="step" value="4" id="step4"/><label for="step4">Step4</label>
<input type="radio" name="step" value="4" id="step5"/><label for="step5">Step5</label>

<svg viewBox="0 -5 100 30">
<defs>
<style>
#line{
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

</style>
</defs>
<path d="M90,20 L15,20 A5,5 0 1 1 15,10 L85,10 A5,5 0 1 0 85,0 L 10,0" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
<path id="line" d="M90,20 L15,20 A5,5 0 1 1 15,10 L85,10 A5,5 0 1 0 85,0 L 10,0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 260 0" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но почему то нету анимации transition...(

Comment: @IlyaZakharov какой браузер? сейчас исправим

Comment: @IlyaZakharov Я пытался найти кнопку пригласить в чат, но тщетно. Может быть, зайдете по ссылке? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130765/svg-css-transition

Comment: @DiD Ответ хороший (+)  Только надо решить проблему с отрицательными значениями stroke-dashoffset  Отрицательные значения в safary IOS не работают

Comment: @Alexandr_TT можно сделать наоборот, чтобы светлосерая линия заполнялась, а черная была на фоне. Тогда можно с положительными значениями добиться этого же эффекта

Comment: @DiD или при рисовании линии в векторном редакторе, поменять начало и конец линии местами

Comment: Исправил отрицательные значения. Сейчас выглядит гораздо стабильнее. Хорошая идея поменять местами начало и конец линии. Только редактора у  меня нету, ручками, ручками...

Comment: @DiD ручками хорошо, тренировка мозга и воображения, но есть же Inkscape, мощный, бесплатный, интуитивно понятный, русский интерфейс, скачивается с сайта производителя. Без него не сделаешь кривые `pixel perfect` совпадения с картинкой